# Visual basic nested array string output to an actual array of integers?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

Hy, i have to ask you guys a question.

I have a function that combines me 10 elements of an `array`, that generates me a `string` of all combinations of 5.
the base array is an object so it can be char or integer, in this case is integer 0-9.

```
Dim base() As Object = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}
```

Output from my function can be this

`"012340123501236012370123801239012450124601247012480124901256012570125801259012670126801269012780127901289013450134601347013480134901356013570135801359013670136801369013780137901389014560145701458014590146701468014690147801479014890156701568015690157801579015890167801679016890178902345023460234702348023490235602357023580235902367023680236902378023790238902456024570245802459024670246802469024780247902489025670256802569025780257902589026780267902689027890345603457034580345903467034680346903478034790348903567035680356903578035790358903678036790368903789045670456804569045780457904589046780467904689047890567805679056890578906789123451234612347123481234912356123571235812359123671236812369123781237912389124561245712458124591246712468124691247812479124891256712568125691257812579125891267812679126891278913456134571345813459134671346813469134781347913489135671356813569135781357913589136781367913689137891456714568145691457814579145891467814679146891478915678156791568915789167892345623457234582345923467234682346923478234792348923567235682356923578235792358923678236792368923789245672456824569245782457924589246782467924689247892567825679256892578926789345673456834569345783457934589346783467934689347893567835679356893578936789456784567945689457894678956789"`

and is stored in an object variable ( i say object because i can use the same function to output the same result as char use an object char array:

```
 Dim base() As Object = {"a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"} )
```

After some work if i use the first array:

```
<pre lang="cs">Dim base() As Object = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}</pre>
```

I have managed to recieve this output :

```
myarray = "{{0,1,2,3,4},{0,1,2,3,5},{0,1,2,3,6},{0,1,2,3,7},{0,1,2,3,8},{0,1,2,3,9},{0,1,2,4,5},{0,1,2,4,6},{0,1,2,4,7},{0,1,2,4,8},{0,1,2,4,9},{0,1,2,5,6},{0,1,2,5,7},{0,1,2,5,8},{0,1,2,5,9},{0,1,2,6,7},{0,1,2,6,8},{0,1,2,6,9},{0,1,2,7,8},{0,1,2,7,9},{0,1,2,8,9},{0,1,3,4,5},{0,1,3,4,6},{0,1,3,4,7},{0,1,3,4,8},{0,1,3,4,9},{0,1,3,5,6},{0,1,3,5,7},{0,1,3,5,8},{0,1,3,5,9},{0,1,3,6,7},{0,1,3,6,8},{0,1,3,6,9},{0,1,3,7,8},{0,1,3,7,9},{0,1,3,8,9},{0,1,4,5,6},{0,1,4,5,7},{0,1,4,5,8},{0,1,4,5,9},{0,1,4,6,7},{0,1,4,6,8},{0,1,4,6,9},{0,1,4,7,8},{0,1,4,7,9},{0,1,4,8,9},{0,1,5,6,7},{0,1,5,6,8},{0,1,5,6,9},{0,1,5,7,8},{0,1,5,7,9},{0,1,5,8,9},{0,1,6,7,8},{0,1,6,7,9},{0,1,6,8,9},{0,1,7,8,9},{0,2,3,4,5},{0,2,3,4,6},{0,2,3,4,7},{0,2,3,4,8},{0,2,3,4,9},{0,2,3,5,6},{0,2,3,5,7},{0,2,3,5,8},{0,2,3,5,9},{0,2,3,6,7},{0,2,3,6,8},{0,2,3,6,9},{0,2,3,7,8},{0,2,3,7,9},{0,2,3,8,9},{0,2,4,5,6},{0,2,4,5,7},{0,2,4,5,8},{0,2,4,5,9},{0,2,4,6,7},{0,2,4,6,8},{0,2,4,6,9},{0,2,4,7,8},{0,2,4,7,9},{0,2,4,8,9},{0,2,5,6,7},{0,2,5,6,8},{0,2,5,6,9},{0,2,5,7,8},{0,2,5,7,9},{0,2,5,8,9},{0,2,6,7,8},{0,2,6,7,9},{0,2,6,8,9},{0,2,7,8,9},{0,3,4,5,6},{0,3,4,5,7},{0,3,4,5,8},{0,3,4,5,9},{0,3,4,6,7},{0,3,4,6,8},{0,3,4,6,9},{0,3,4,7,8},{0,3,4,7,9},{0,3,4,8,9},{0,3,5,6,7},{0,3,5,6,8},{0,3,5,6,9},{0,3,5,7,8},{0,3,5,7,9},{0,3,5,8,9},{0,3,6,7,8},{0,3,6,7,9},{0,3,6,8,9},{0,3,7,8,9},{0,4,5,6,7},{0,4,5,6,8},{0,4,5,6,9},{0,4,5,7,8},{0,4,5,7,9},{0,4,5,8,9},{0,4,6,7,8},{0,4,6,7,9},{0,4,6,8,9},{0,4,7,8,9},{0,5,6,7,8},{0,5,6,7,9},{0,5,6,8,9},{0,5,7,8,9},{0,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,6},{1,2,3,4,7},{1,2,3,4,8},{1,2,3,4,9},{1,2,3,5,6},{1,2,3,5,7},{1,2,3,5,8},{1,2,3,5,9},{1,2,3,6,7},{1,2,3,6,8},{1,2,3,6,9},{1,2,3,7,8},{1,2,3,7,9},{1,2,3,8,9},{1,2,4,5,6},{1,2,4,5,7},{1,2,4,5,8},{1,2,4,5,9},{1,2,4,6,7},{1,2,4,6,8},{1,2,4,6,9},{1,2,4,7,8},{1,2,4,7,9},{1,2,4,8,9},{1,2,5,6,7},{1,2,5,6,8},{1,2,5,6,9},{1,2,5,7,8},{1,2,5,7,9},{1,2,5,8,9},{1,2,6,7,8},{1,2,6,7,9},{1,2,6,8,9},{1,2,7,8,9},{1,3,4,5,6},{1,3,4,5,7},{1,3,4,5,8},{1,3,4,5,9},{1,3,4,6,7},{1,3,4,6,8},{1,3,4,6,9},{1,3,4,7,8},{1,3,4,7,9},{1,3,4,8,9},{1,3,5,6,7},{1,3,5,6,8},{1,3,5,6,9},{1,3,5,7,8},{1,3,5,7,9},{1,3,5,8,9},{1,3,6,7,8},{1,3,6,7,9},{1,3,6,8,9},{1,3,7,8,9},{1,4,5,6,7},{1,4,5,6,8},{1,4,5,6,9},{1,4,5,7,8},{1,4,5,7,9},{1,4,5,8,9},{1,4,6,7,8},{1,4,6,7,9},{1,4,6,8,9},{1,4,7,8,9},{1,5,6,7,8},{1,5,6,7,9},{1,5,6,8,9},{1,5,7,8,9},{1,6,7,8,9},{2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,7},{2,3,4,5,8},{2,3,4,5,9},{2,3,4,6,7},{2,3,4,6,8},{2,3,4,6,9},{2,3,4,7,8},{2,3,4,7,9},{2,3,4,8,9},{2,3,5,6,7},{2,3,5,6,8},{2,3,5,6,9},{2,3,5,7,8},{2,3,5,7,9},{2,3,5,8,9},{2,3,6,7,8},{2,3,6,7,9},{2,3,6,8,9},{2,3,7,8,9},{2,4,5,6,7},{2,4,5,6,8},{2,4,5,6,9},{2,4,5,7,8},{2,4,5,7,9},{2,4,5,8,9},{2,4,6,7,8},{2,4,6,7,9},{2,4,6,8,9},{2,4,7,8,9},{2,5,6,7,8},{2,5,6,7,9},{2,5,6,8,9},{2,5,7,8,9},{2,6,7,8,9},{3,4,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6,8},{3,4,5,6,9},{3,4,5,7,8},{3,4,5,7,9},{3,4,5,8,9},{3,4,6,7,8},{3,4,6,7,9},{3,4,6,8,9},{3,4,7,8,9},{3,5,6,7,8},{3,5,6,7,9},{3,5,6,8,9},{3,5,7,8,9},{3,6,7,8,9},{4,5,6,7,8},{4,5,6,7,9},{4,5,6,8,9},{4,5,7,8,9},{4,6,7,8,9},{5,6,7,8,9}} "
```

that is stored in an `object` variable.

My question is how to transform the output above(the object variable) in an actual multi `dimensional array`?

Ex:`Dim convertedarray() = convert(myarray)`

My second question is how to calculate all `arrays` from above(myarray) and store the results in in another `multi dimensional array` for ex: `dim myresults = calculate(myarray)` to output something like this: `myresults = {{10},{11},{etc....}}` this is only when i use integer arrays, i dont want to calculate chars one...

Comment: Do you want to find all combinations or permutations? (using the mathematical definitions)

Comment: Could you post the function that generates the output string?

Comment: this example above uses combinations, this is not my point. 
i cannot post the function that generates the output strings its just math + parse nothing to see here.

This is only thing i want to know how:
I have 2 variables
one string variable that stores an exact representation of a multidimension nested array
and a second variable that actualy stores the array from the first one
dim var1 as string= "{({0,1,2,3,4}),({0,1,2,3,5}),({0,1,2,3,6})}"
i want
dim var2() = someconvertfunction(var1) and finaly variable to to have this value = {({0,1,2,3,4}),({0,1,2,3,5}),({0,1,2,3,6})}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written up a quick example of converting a string to a 2D array, if you know regular expressions you could simplify it a bit more.

But I think you'd find it a lot easier to build it up as you find your combinations.

Also, using lists might be more straightforward, you wont need to calculate a dimension size.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Arraystring As String = "{{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5,1},{3,4,5,1,2}}"


    Dim comboTotal As Integer = 3
    Dim comboSize As Integer = 5
    'Need to know dimension sizes to create 2d array - otherwise use list
    Dim DimensionalArray(comboTotal, comboSize) As Integer


    Console.WriteLine("Initial String: " & Arraystring & vbNewLine)


    'Clean up string into CSV
    Dim subStringList() As String = Arraystring.Split("},")


    For i = 0 To subStringList.Count - 1
        subStringList(i) = subStringList(i).Replace(",{", "")
        subStringList(i) = subStringList(i).Replace("{", "")
        Console.WriteLine(subStringList(i))
    Next

    'Start adding and moving down the array
    For i = 0 To subStringList.Count - 1

        'Count array index
        Dim numCount = 0

        'Read in each number - implictly converted to int
        For Each number In subStringList(i).Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Console.WriteLine("Adding Value: " & number)
            DimensionalArray(i, numCount) = number

            'Move along the array
            numCount += 1
        Next
    Next



    'Try accessing some elements of the new array
    Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "Accessing [0][4]: " & DimensionalArray(0, 4))
    Console.WriteLine("Accessing [1][2]: " & DimensionalArray(1, 2))
    Console.WriteLine("Accessing [2][0]: " & DimensionalArray(2, 0))


    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

[image: Console Output]

Comment: Finnaly, at least someone that understand's me, i have posted to codeproject(already closed) and msdn and people say they dont understand my question but its simple, i have to admit, i was wrong on the post above with arrays i forgot "()" 
{({1,2,3,4,5}), ({etc})}"
i have a function that makes combination c(n,k), 10/5 and the output is 256 arrays of 5 so comboTotal is 256
i just want from this: here i posted the question updated and simpler than this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/099a9e10-93d2-4c1d-86f5-aad64f9f3a33/multidimensional-nested-arrays?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: also i want a method of contact you please, i have some further questions if i may ask you.

Comment: For round brackets just remove them first using the replace function. E.g. `subStringList(i) = subStringList(i).Replace("(", "")` If you have other questions create a new one and I'll try help if I have time.